# Drawing A Line In The Sand

Tags: discussion, comments

So, as much as I'll tell myself it's non-harmful... I post sarcastic responses to poorly asked questions.

Case and point: [Getting Visual Studio to display the C# code that's causing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126739/getting-unhelpful-js-errors-from-a-script-when-debugging-my-c-sharp-button#comment37224582_24126739)

I doge-sarcasmed for lack of detail. I do this a lot, because closing bad questions is very tedious and there are hundreds every day. It's how I let off steam without cursing out somebody :P

If the question actually shows effort to help us help them, I can be as helpful as can be.

But what is the line in the sand when it comes to commenting on poorly asked, probable to be closed questions? Obviously berating or abuse is crossing the line, but is general sarcasm or joking ok?

Please note that just because it's sarcastic, doesn't mean it's not constructive, nor does it mean the opposite.

Comment: Think of it this way, if you were a newish user to the site would you like people being sarcastic and rude in the comments?  Comments should be constructive to the user and post. BTW I've since removed the comment because there was absolutely nothing constructive about it.

Comment: no, even if your joke isn't mean at all, but is just funny, if it's not constructive it should be flagged. Comments are for suggestions, questions, and so on, not for jokes. Sometimes on meta a joke is ok, but not on a main site.

Comment: @bluefeet no worries. But I was a new user who did get sarcastic responses, and on my end it made me want to "get back at" said person by posting something good. But that's just me.

Comment: There may not be enough information there to actually answer -- I'm completely unfamiliar with VS -- but OP is asking for help configuring the IDE for debugging, _not for SO to debug code e hasn't supplied_. It's not a great point for your case.

Comment: @KateGregory sarcasm isn't always a joke. Some people simply only respond to negativity on their posts, while completely ignoring every question, comment, that is aimed to help. (I see it in chat all the time)

Comment: @JoshCaswell it's not just that question. It's on dozens of questions each day

Comment: Sure, but I'm saying that one isn't a particularly good piece of evidence.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yeah I was looking for a better example but I don't know a way to view my past comments

Comment: @RUJordan on your profile page got to "Activity" then "Comments"

Comment: If you consistently down-voted / close-voted those posts, votes are recorded there for mods and you, too.

Comment: @codeMagic no way! I never knew that! Thanks!

Comment: People working in their second language may not recognize sarcasm. On the cooking site someone asked "can I put cheddar on a pizza?" and I was tempted to comment "No, you will be arrested by the pizza police" to demonstrate that of course you can put whatever cheese you want on pizza, it just might not taste good or whatever. But I did not. And I think you should not either. It doesn't actually help the asker improve and it doesn't encourage a helpful atmosphere.

Comment: @KateGregory that's actually a very good point, not much wiggle room there for me lol

Comment: Off topic but when 3 moderators answer your question... it's pretty hard to go against that xD

Comment: @RUJordan I almost never see people respond to negativity in the way that you want them too.  It's counterproductive because it makes them defiant.

Comment: Sarcastic answers are unhelpful as the "answer" gets lost in the "snark" noise. If someone is asking a question, regardless of how poorly written it is, they're taking a risk - they're putting their lack of knowledge on display and asking for help. Snarky, sarcastic answers and comments are a bullys way of attacking that risk. I think we all know how to behave - be polite and share with others. We should have all learned this in kindergarten (or the equivalent in your country of origin :-). If some people find this difficult, perhaps now is the time to make the effort to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Of course you know those comments aren't appropriate. If you thought they were, you wouldn't have posted this. [Robert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259972/drawing-a-line-in-the-sand/259973#259973) and [bluefeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259972/drawing-a-line-in-the-sand/259974#259974) explain *why* they're not appropriate, but you didn't really need that - even as you felt compelled to post that last comment, some part of you recoiled from it.

If I had to guess, I'd say it's because you know what Stack Overflow would be like if everyone did that. If every question became a competition, not for the best answer but for the "funniest" comment. Maybe you've seen sites that've gone down that road, seen how demotivating it becomes to the folks who *would* contribute positively while doing nothing to stop the endless flood of bad questions... I know I have.

But that doesn't make it any easier to see one lousy question after another. Sooner or later, the anger and frustration starts to build... Laughing at them becomes a coping mechanism, a way of diffusing that frustration before it spills out (as you say) in cursing and vitriol. At least, that's how it was for me.

These days, I tend to prefer chat for this. First, because I'm not pouring out my frustration with hundreds of clueless people on the head of one unlucky soul. Second, because my stupid jokes aren't cluttering up the site.

But if you *really* feel like you gotta make a joke in the comments, make the most of it: try to *educate* with humor instead of tearing down.

#### See also:

- [Should Sarcasm be Acceptable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/should-sarcasm-be-acceptable)
- [Is humor allowed in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/is-humor-allowed-in-answers)

Comment: I wont lie, you couldn't have been more accurate. I posted this because I was a bit worried about my "habit" of dealing with bad questions over and over. I do take my time on several a day to try, but I get burnt out eventually. It just... sometimes hard, you know? This site has basically trained me where college failed, and all I see now is just.. lazy people trying to get us to google code for them.

Comment: @RUJordan When you are so frustrated that you feel being sarcastic/snarky is your way of dealing with it, then maybe it's time to take a break from it.  We all have days when we are frustrated with what we see but putting it into comments isn't the best way to deal with it.

Comment: I guess I feel obligated to clean Main as best I can, even if it means being construed as an ass sometimes. Maybe if I feel burnt out I should just take a break and ignore them. (This is also the reason I avoid the review sector)

Comment: Personally, I find that some of my "best" comments and answers are the ones I don't post. I'll read a question and, yeah, I'll *write* the snarky/sarcastic/nasty comment or answer (because, I suppose, deep down I'm still a snarky, sarcastic, nasty little barstud :-) - and then I'll take a deep breath, erase it, and write the answer *I should have written first*. And thus one more step is taken on the long road to enlightenment...

Comment: @BobJarvis You're not going to be the FGITW like that!  ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard : I'd rather be right than President. (Actually, I'd rather be just about anything than President... :-)

Answer (score 17):

Comments should be used to ask for further information, suggestions or additional questions to the user about the post.

Your comment was:

> wow. such descript. very error. much debug. so details. wow. –  RUJordan 12 mins ago

Which doesn't fit into any of the categories.

If you feel that a question is poorly worded or should be closed, then feel free to downvote, vote to close or comment constructively about how the OP can improve their post.  Posting comments that are filled with sarcasm and/or snark is not beneficial to the community and will most likely be removed.

Comment: Instead of repeating myself -- i'll just point you to my comment on Shog's answer (that one really hit home for me). I'm not mean, I guess I'm just tired of closing questions all day instead of answering them

Comment: @RUJordan Hey, I get it I've been there, I'm sure we all have.  That's when it's time to step away from the pc and get some fresh air. :)

Comment: WHAT IS FRESH AIR?!

Answer (score 8):

Comments have two sanctioned purposes: to clarify a post, or ask for clarification.

That's it.  Any other use subjects them to removal.

Comment: Fair enough. I can't say that I'll never be sarcastic, but I'll make a good effort to make it constructive, and definitely not rude. Thanks for your time

Comment: What about if you think an answer might be incomplete?  Can you use a comment for that?

Comment: @Sam That's a clarification.